# IIS7 native module issues

Tags: iis-7, module, native

I'm developing a small IIS7 native module.

I can't seem to get any output from it when I make page requests in IIS.

So I've taken a step backward to trying to make one of the msdn samples work first.  Trouble is - I can't get any output from that either...

The sample is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693622(VS.90).aspx

I've done the following:

. Made sure that i've exported RegisterModule

. Built the module as a Win32 dll

. Added a test site with a web.config, and test.aspx page that just displays "hello world"

. Added the native module into IIS at server level using the IIS gui

. Added a handler mapping at site level for "*.aspx", all verbs, for my module.

. Restarted IIS

I can see my web.config has been updated to include:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="EndRequestModule" path="*.aspx" verb="*" modules="MyHttpModule" scriptProcessor="<REALPATHISINHERE>\endRequestModule.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="bitness32" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

At this point i'm expecting to see lines in the event viewer when I make requests - but nothing.

I've also added some "OutputDebugString" calls to try and see when the modules load or respond to requests, but I don't see any output there either, which makes me think im missing something configesque...

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate x64 and VS2010 - are there any extras I need to install or other things to config (possibly between x86 and x64) because it's not a server os?

Any thoughts on what I could be missing would be welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: fwiw procexp shows that my w3wp process is x64, my dll is currently x86, adding a project configuration for x64 and rebuilding the dll targeting x64 results in a 503, service unavailable and the application pool stops, the event viewer shows an access violation error....  I'm sure this is something to with x86 vs x64, can I force the test site to run as x86 instead of x64 to just test the POC?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed.

There is no need for handler mappings unless you need to filter specifically, it is enough to install your modules at server level, and then remove at site level for sites that do no need your module.

Application pool advanced settings in IIS - Set Enable 32 Bit Applications to TRUE to test the POC.

Then rebuild the DLL for an x64 platform, uninstall your existing module, install the x64 one, set Enable 32 bit applications to FALSE, and test the x64 module.

OutputDebugString calls now show in DbgView as well.

Comment: I'm attempting to do the same thing on Win7 64 and VS2010. I've built my module for x64 but the app pool stops and I get a 503 error. I've done exactly what you said above. I'm still troubleshooting. Any advice you can give me?

Comment: Actually I just figured out what my issue was and it was the fact that IIS 7 couldn't load a module from the visual studio project which was under my profile. I had to copy the dll outside of my profile directory and then IIS 7 was happy to load it. HAHA!